# What are the good blog/rss feeds about SEO?

Tags: seo, blog, suggestions

What are good blogs or RSS feeds about Search Engine Optimization ?

Comment: Heh, a question with answers destined for link rot. Ye times, they have changed.

Answer (score 7):

**[Matt Cutts' Blog](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/type/googleseo/) and [Sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/)**

**Matt Cutts Blog** - Matt Cutts is the head of Google’s Webspam team so he definitely has a valuable inside perspective of how the Google webcrawler works. In the Blogosphere, what John Skeet is to C#, Matt Cutts is to SEO.

**Sitepoint.com** - Sitepoint is more of a news site than a blog and it isn't directly geared toward SEO but it does a great job of covering all the bases. Some of the best articles found online about SEO can be found @ SitePoint. I highly recommend it.

See:

- [The Ultimate SEO Checklist](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ultimate-seo-checklist).
- [The Top 10 Google Myths Revealed](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/top-10-google-myths-revealed)
- [Secret Benefits of Search Engine Optimisation: Increased Usability](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/increased-usability)

I could keep going adding more examples from SitePoint but I'd be up all night reading articles on Search Engine and Website Optimizations.

If there was a de-facto authoritative news site for everything web (dev/publishing/webmaster) it would be SitePoint.

**Update: Added Matt Cutts' blog.**

Answer (score 5):

[SEOMOZ.org](http://www.seomoz.org/blog) has some interesting articles, though there is the occasional plug for their services.

Answer (score 3):

[Official Google Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/) is good.

[SearchEngineLand](http://searchengineland.com/), by Danny Sullivan is great too.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the best SEO feeds are about creating great content. Pro Blogger is the best http://www.problogger.net/

From there he should suggest the rest to you organically.

Answer (score 0):

[Official Google webmasters help Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp/videos) - just search for what you need and there will be at least one short video by Matt Cutts available.

There's nothing more that getting it right from the source, Matt Cutts is the head of Google's Webspam team :)